# Animation circular container along the rectangular shape in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

in this flutter project when I make the animation in a rectangular shape or any unequally sides shape unless square, I found  the equally vertical distances between each container is less than the equally horizontal distances between each container and also the vertical speed is less than the horizontal speed so I want to make the space between each container is equal along the rectangle total length and make the speed constant along the rectangle total length , this is the output i want to modify it [image: output image]
this the code :

```
class AnimatedContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedContainer({super.key});

  @override
  State<AnimatedContainer> createState() =>
      _AnimatedContainerState();
}

class _AnimatedContainerState extends State<AnimatedContainer>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  double dotSize = 10.0;
  double x = 286;
  int numBalls = 40; // Number of balls

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 7), //Speed of balls
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    _controller.repeat();
  }

  double _getPositionX(double value) {
    value = (value % 1);
    // Use % to keep value within [0, 1]
    if (value < 0.25) {
      //@ value (x) = 0 ,returned value (y) = 0
      //@ value (x) = 0.25 , returned value (y) = 286
      //slope = (286-0)/(0.25-0) = 4*286
      //path equation : y = slope*x + constant
      //path equation : y = (4*286)*value + c , by sub c= 0
      // y = 4*286*value
      //use the previous steps in the next conditions
      return 4 * 286 * value;
    } else if (value < 0.5) {
      return 286;
    } else if (value < 0.75) {
      return (-4 * value + 3) * 286;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  double _getPositionY(double value) {
    value = (value % 1);
    if (value < 0.25) {
      return 0;
    } else if (value < 0.5) {
      //@ value (x) = 0.25 ,returned value (y) = 0
      //@ value (x) = 0.5 , returned value (y) = 137
      //slope = (137-0)/(0.5-0.25) = 4*137
      //path equation : y = slope*x + constant
      //path equation : y = (4*137)*value + c , by sub c = -137
      // y = 4*137*value - 137 = (4*value - 1)*137
      //use the previous steps in the next conditions
      return (4 * value - 1) * 137;
    } else if (value < 0.75) {
      return 137;
    } else {
      return (4 - 4 * value) * 137;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenwidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double screenheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double paddleft = screenwidth / 2 - 143;
    double paddtop = screenheight / 2 - 68.5;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < numBalls; i++)
              Positioned(
                left: (paddleft) +
                    _getPositionX(_controller.value - i / numBalls),
                // Adjust position
                top: (paddtop) +
                    _getPositionY(
                        _controller.value - i / numBalls), // Adjust position
                child: Container(
                  width: dotSize,
                  height: dotSize,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I try to make distribution distances between each container along the rectangle total length is equal and make the container speed is constant along it`s rectangular path.