# Animate a flutter widget in a specific path

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

How i can create this animation with flutter [image: desired output animation]

I tried to use `AnimationController` i found it suitable for square path but for rectangular path,the animation speed isn't constant along the path and also the distances between each container along the rectangular path are different
[image: undesired output animation]

Comment: its better to share the code you have been try. so people can help to add some logic

Comment: @pmatatias This is the code in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76992967/animation-circular-container-along-the-rectangular-shape-in-flutter

Comment: use `CustomPaint` for things like that

Comment: @pskink thank you ,it works well , `CustomPaint` is the best solution until now.